# SharePoint 2016 OnPremise ULS Logs error - User-Agent is empty

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, uls, logs

We are getting one constant error `User-Agent is empty.` in ULS logs in SharePoint 2016 On-premise server.
And due to this error, Our logs disk space is getting full.

Please let me know some troubleshooting steps for the same.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can ignore this. It just means that the call being made by the client (or likely by a service) doesn't contain a user agent string.

Comment: Understood. But suddenly this error is coming more often and has flooded my disk space. I checked verbose settings and all but those are disabled. I am confused like to what to do to decrease the log size.

Comment: You can use `Set-SPDiagnosticConfig -LogDiskSpaceUsageGB 10` which would limit the ULS log to a total of 10GB. Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/set-spdiagnosticconfig?view=sharepoint-server-ps